# Use an AngularJS Service in place of the url in KendoUI Scheduler

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I've passed all day long trying to figure out while using a kendoui scheduler adapter for AngularJS the events were not loaded successfully and I found that the reason was the Service's call to get data; replacing it with the URL it correctly works, but it seems so ugly to me. Is there a way I can use it and have things working?

Here's the code I use

```
angular.module('xxx.controllers').controller('CalendarioController', [
'$scope', '$rootScope', '$mdDialog', '$mdToast', 'CalendarioService',
function ($scope, $rootScope, $mdDialog, $mdToast, CalendarioService) {
    var self = this;
    self.scope = $scope;
    self.service = CalendarioService;
    self.scope.loading = false;

    self.scope.nuovoEventoCalendario = function (ev) {

        $mdDialog.show({
            controller: 'NuovoEventoCalendarioController',
            templateUrl: '/amministratori/calendario/form',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: ev,
            locals: {
                // nada
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            if (response) {
                //caricaListaEtichette();
                // Qui apro il popup con la preview del barcode
                //  self.scope.anteprimaDiStampa(response, ev);
            }
        }, function () {

        });
    };

    self.scope.schedulerOptions = {
        date: new Date(),
        views: [
            "day",
            //"workWeek",
            "week",
            { type: "month", selected: true },

        ],
        //editable: {
        //    template: $("#customEditorTemplate").html(),
        dataSource: {
            batch: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    type: "GET",
                    datatype: "json",
                    url: "https://localhost:44301/api/calendario/elenco", //This works
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                },
                //read: {
                //    url: CalendarioService.getElencoEventiCalendario(), //This not
                //    dataType: "json"
                //},
```

The strange thing is that the service's method is defined as follow

```
angular.module('xxx.services').factory('CalendarioService', [
'$http', function ($http) {
    var baseUrl = "api/calendario";

    return {
        getElencoEventiCalendario: function () {
    return $http.get(baseUrl + "/elenco");
        },
```

The thing I suspect is that the method is a promise and not the URL itself... how can I fix this issue by the way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The $http service returns a promise. Data is extracted from a promise with the `.then` method of that promise. See [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - The Promise API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api).

Answer (score 0):

Like already said you need to use .then as the $http service returns a promise. You can try something like that:

```
dataSource: {
            transport: {
              read: function (e) {
                CalendarioService.getElencoEventiCalendario()
                  .then(function success(response) {
                  e.success(response.data)
                }, function error(response) {
                  alert('something went wrong')
                  console.log(response);
                })
              }
            }
          }
```

Hope this helps.